# Undefined reference to a method in a pure abstract class

Tags: c++, oop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <set>

class Locuinta {

protected:
    std::string numeClient;
    double pret;
    int suprafata;
    int discount;
public:
    virtual double calculChirie() const = 0;
    virtual void citire() = 0;
    virtual void afisare() = 0;

};

class Apartament : public Locuinta {

    int etaj;
public:
    double calculChirie() const;
    void citire();
    void afisare();

};

double Apartament::calculChirie() const {

    double chirie = 0;
    chirie = suprafata * pret;
    if (discount != 0) {
        chirie *= (discount * 0.01);
    }
    return chirie;

}
```

I have these two classes Locuinta and Apartment. There are three abstract methods in the class Locuinta: calculChirie(), citire() and afisare(). When I run the code, I am getting the following errors:

```
undefined reference to `Apartament::citire()
undefined reference to Apartament::afisare()
error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, I only get these errors if I implement the method Apartament::calculChirie(). So, why does the implementation of the method calculChirie affects the other virtual methods? And what should I do to fix it?

Comment: `what should I do to fix it?` Implement the methods.

Comment: @tkausl I can't believe it was that easy:))) Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's "ill-formed, no diagnostic required" to have any non-pure virtual methods without bodies, whether or not you actually call the functions anywhere.  The compiler is allowed to give a warning or error but doesn't have to.

Perhaps what happened here is that the compiler didn't bother to generate a vtable while there were no virtual method bodies; but as soon as you added one then it tried to generate the vtable and could not find the bodies for the other methods.

As mentioned in comments, implementing the methods is a good fix .